# spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE is using missing class com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf

I have tried every way I could find to make this dependency available to my application.  Is this a bug in spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE or spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE?  Is there a way to resolve this?

Here is the stack trace which shows the spring versions:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createDocument': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at
```

Some more details here to continue post of stack trace:

```
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at my.app.Application.main(Application.java:22) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:344) ~[cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:342) ~[cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:342) ~[cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:243) ~[cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:472) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:327) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86) ~[cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:425) ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:527) ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:262) ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:168) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:460) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:338) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:255) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:543) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1645) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        ... 63 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you post a [minimum complete and verifiable version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code?

Comment: Most probably there's more than 1 dependency with this class in your classpath. Depends on your build tool

Answer (score 0):

check your pom.xml and makesure you have the dependency imported,such as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did try these and they did not fix the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to resolve this dependency.  I finally found these to help with the versions seen in the above stack trace in the question.  You may not need all of them depending on what you are trying to do.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-jxc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
    <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.24</version>
</dependency>
```